# form does not submit accented vowels , is there a way to correct this trouble?

Tags: php, html, forms, character-encoding

I bring another question related with form for you :

1- The code pasted below is a php processed form which submits the information to an email.
It works perfectly except that when fields are filled with a word that has the character ã 
then I receive the following :

```
From :
Sílv &#227 ; o 

e-Mail : joao@qualquercoisa.com.br 
Subject : [Formulário de contato] : ão é í ó ú ça 
Message : ão é í ó ú ça ão é í ó ú ça ão é í ó ú ça ão é í ó ú ça
```

The number #227; is the ASCII Character Code for ã. All other accented vowels are submitted correctly.
Is there a way to correct this problem ?

2- On another matter what has to be added to the code to process radiobuttons and checkboxes ?

Thank you

```
Quote
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
<title>Líderes do Futuro</title>

<!-- the cascading style sheet-->
<link href="../css/style_contactform.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>


<body>
<div id="contentForm">

<!-- The contact form starts from here-->
<?php
$error = ''; // error message
$name = ''; // sender's name
$email = ''; // sender's email address
$subject = ''; // subject
$message = ''; // the message itself
$spamcheck = ''; // Spam check

if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$spamcheck = $_POST['spamcheck'];

if(trim($name) == '')
{
$error = '<div class="errormsg">Por favor complete seu nome</div>';
}
else if(trim($email) == '')
{
$error = '<div class="errormsg">Por favor complete seu nome digite seu e-mail</div>';
}
else if(!isEmail($email))
{
$error = '<div class="errormsg">You have enter an invalid e-mail address. Please, try again!</div>';
}
if(trim($subject) == '')
{
$error = '<div class="errormsg">Please enter a subject!</div>';
}
else if(trim($message) == '')
{
$error = '<div class="errormsg">Please enter your message!</div>';
}
else if(trim($spamcheck) == '')
{
$error = '<div class="errormsg">Please enter the number for Spam Check!</div>';
}
else if(trim($spamcheck) != '5')
{
$error = '<div class="errormsg">Spam Check: The number you entered is not correct! 2 + 3 = ???</div>';
}
if($error == '')
{
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$message = stripslashes($message);
}

// the email will be sent here
// make sure to change this to be your e-mail
$to = "johndoe@bogieman.com";

// the email subject
// '[Contact Form] :' will appear automatically in the subject.
// You can change it as you want

$subject = '[Formulário de contato] : ' . $subject;

// the mail message ( add any additional information if you want )
$msg = "From : $name \r\ne-Mail : $email \r\nSubject : $subject \r\n\n" . "Message : \r\n$message";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n");
?>

<!-- Message sent! (change the text below as you wish)-->
<div style="text-align:center;">
<h1>Congratulations!!</h1>
<p>Thank you <b><?=$name;?></b>, your message is sent!</p>
</div>
<!--End Message Sent-->


<?php
}
}

if(!isset($_POST['send']) || $error != '')
{
?>

<h2>Preencha todos os campos:</h2>
<!--Error Message-->
<?=$error;?>

<form method="post" name="contFrm" id="contFrm" action="">


<label><span class="required">*</span> Full Name:</label>
<input name="name" type="text" class="box" id="name" size="30" value="<?=$name;?>" />




<label><span class="required">*</span> Email: </label>
<input name="email" type="text" class="box" id="email" size="30" value="<?=$email;?>" />

<label><span class="required">*</span> Subject: </label>
<input name="subject" type="text" class="box" id="subject" size="30" value="<?=$subject;?>" />

<label><span class="required">*</span> Message: </label>
<textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="3" id="message"><?=$message;?></textarea>

<label><span class="required">*</span> Spam Check: <b>2 + 3=</b></label>
<input name="spamcheck" type="text" class="box" id="spamcheck" size="4" value="<?=$spamcheck;?>" /><br /><br />

<!-- Submit Button-->
<input name="send" type="submit" class="button" id="send" value="" />

</form>

<!-- E-mail verification. Do not edit -->
<?php
}

function isEmail($email)
{
return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i"
,$email));
}
?>
<!-- END CONTACT FORM -->


</div> <!-- /contentForm -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`My 2 cents:` From the tests I made, either remove the `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">` altogether, or replace the `1250` to `1252`. Tests returned the characters `ão` correctly instead of `&#227;`

Comment: @Ron Wolpa check and verify charset. If this was your problem, UPvote and check to accept this answer. Hope it works out.

Comment: Switching from one 8-bit legacy character set to another will only push the problem elsewhere. You should consider upgrading to the 21st century, i. e. UTF-8.

Comment: My 2 cents: From the tests I made......> Nope , unfortunetaly changing the chartset to 1252 , nor removing altogether the doctype has  made it to return the vowels accented with the tilde.  
What tests exactly you made ?

Comment: @RonWolpa I used the form with different charsets, best one was 1252. Yet, did not try UTF-8 (tripleee) which you might want to try yourself. Other than that, you will have to keep searching here or elsewhere on the web. Good luck.

Comment: To : My 2 cents
Absolutely right , switched to 1252 to finally receive the ao AO with tilde  : ão ÃO even with capital letters, than you very much

Comment: @RonWolpa Anytime. However as tripleee mentioned, it might push the problem elsewhere. Try UTF-8 also. Checkmark to accept as answer. Buenas dias ;-)

Comment: (Buenos Dias)
I will give a try on UFT-8 as well of course.
Now I have another problem :

Comment: (Buenos Dias in Spanish , in portuguese would be Bom dia)
I will give a try on UFT-8 as well of course.
Now I have another problem : I added another $to      = "johndoe@nobody.com"; , the 2nd one is $to2 to send a copy to another email account ; it worked fine , both email accounts receive the message , $to the accented vowels are ok , but not $to2 ; God this is the trickiest thing I´ve stumbled over in my life ! any sugestion ?

Comment: To Fred / Tripleee :  about UFT-8 , would you please paste me the complete doctype code with UFT-8;  I do not know exactly what you mean , I am amazed with the bizarre behavior of PHP processing the form. The problem with tilde + letter A is very odd. 
Help me to run a test with UNIF-8.
By the way where exactly you get information about unicode and doctype?

Comment: @RonWolpa Try this instead $to = 'email1@somewhere.xxx, email2@somewhere.xxx';

Comment: @RonWolpa `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: @Fred :  1- changed the meta as you posted , all the accented vowels are messed. Perhaps the doctype is not compatible with UTF 8 ??

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: @RonWolpa why is there a `;` after `<head>` and before <html xmlns?

Answer (score 1):

Copy/paste code below. Another problem may be with your CSS Stylesheet. Try removing the link to .css and inserting directly into the `<head>` or have no style at all. Code below sends to 2 emails. After this Ron, I don't know how else I can be of help, because this works fine for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Líderes do Futuro</title>

<!-- the cascading style sheet-->
<link href="../css/style_contactform.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>


<body>
<div id="contentForm">

<!-- The contact form starts from here-->
<?php
$error = ''; // error message
$name = ''; // sender's name
$email = ''; // sender's email address
$subject = ''; // subject
$message = ''; // the message itself
$spamcheck = ''; // Spam check

if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$spamcheck = $_POST['spamcheck'];

if(trim($name) == '')
{
$error = '<div class="errormsg">Por favor complete seu nome</div>';
}
else if(trim($email) == '')
{
$error = '<div class="errormsg">Por favor complete seu nome digite seu e-mail</div>';
}
else if(!isEmail($email))
{
$error = '<div class="errormsg">You have enter an invalid e-mail address. Please, try again!</div>';
}
if(trim($subject) == '')
{
$error = '<div class="errormsg">Please enter a subject!</div>';
}
else if(trim($message) == '')
{
$error = '<div class="errormsg">Please enter your message!</div>';
}
else if(trim($spamcheck) == '')
{
$error = '<div class="errormsg">Please enter the number for Spam Check!</div>';
}
else if(trim($spamcheck) != '5')
{
$error = '<div class="errormsg">Spam Check: The number you entered is not correct! 2 + 3 = ???</div>';
}
if($error == '')
{
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$message = stripslashes($message);
}

// the email will be sent here
// make sure to change this to be your e-mail
// $to = "johndoe@bogieman.com";
$to = 'email1@somesite.xxx, email2@somesite.xxx';

// the email subject
// '[Contact Form] :' will appear automatically in the subject.
// You can change it as you want

$subject = '[Formulário de contato] : ' . $subject;

// the mail message ( add any additional information if you want )
$msg = "From : $name \r\ne-Mail : $email \r\nSubject : $subject \r\n\n" . "Message : \r\n$message";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n");
?>

<!-- Message sent! (change the text below as you wish)-->
<div style="text-align:center;">
<h1>Congratulations!!</h1>
<p>Thank you <b><?=$name;?></b>, your message is sent!</p>
</div>
<!--End Message Sent-->


<?php
}
}

if(!isset($_POST['send']) || $error != '')
{
?>

<h2>Preencha todos os campos:</h2>
<!--Error Message-->
<?=$error;?>

<form method="post" name="contFrm" id="contFrm" action="">


<label><span class="required">*</span> Full Name:</label>
<input name="name" type="text" class="box" id="name" size="30" value="<?=$name;?>" />




<label><span class="required">*</span> Email: </label>
<input name="email" type="text" class="box" id="email" size="30" value="<?=$email;?>" />

<label><span class="required">*</span> Subject: </label>
<input name="subject" type="text" class="box" id="subject" size="30" value="<?=$subject;?>" />

<label><span class="required">*</span> Message: </label>
<textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="3" id="message"><?=$message;?></textarea>

<label><span class="required">*</span> Spam Check: <b>2 + 3=</b></label>
<input name="spamcheck" type="text" class="box" id="spamcheck" size="4" value="<?=$spamcheck;?>" /><br /><br />

<!-- Submit Button-->
<input name="send" type="submit" class="button" id="send" value="" />

</form>

<!-- E-mail verification. Do not edit -->
<?php
}

function isEmail($email)
{
return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i"
,$email));
}
?>
<!-- END CONTACT FORM -->


</div> <!-- /contentForm -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried the code above with and without the **[tag:bom]** and it works fine, so that's not your problem. Another thing, are you uploading in **ASCII**? May be a stupid question, but worth asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ron,

Look into this [strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) and also this:

`filter_var`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

a great tutorial :

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Filtering-Data-with-PHP.html

In regards to your checkbox question [read here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3201813.htm)

Comment: the example is for checkbox , I ask if I can follow the same logic for one choice radiobuttons :

<input type="radio" name="radioarray[]" value="one">First
 
<input type="radio" name="radioarray[]" value="two">Second 

<input type="radio" name="radioarray[]" value="three">Third